# Why is $\Omega$ used to denote the space of differential forms?

Tags: notation, manifolds, differential-forms

A simple curious question about notation. The space of $k$-differential forms over a manifold $M$ is typically denoted by $\Omega^k(M)$. Does anybody know why, or where this notation originated? It would make sense to call them $A^k(M)$, for alternating, or $\Lambda^k(M)$, in reference to the wedge (I think some communities actually use these notations). Why the $\Omega$, then? Is there any record on where it was first used?

Comment: There is a reason why we don't use $\Lambda(M)$ --- what if $M$ is a vector space $V$?  $\Lambda(V)$ was already taken by the alternating algebra on $V$ which is the pointwise model.  And we don't want to keep writing $C^\infty \Lambda^k T^*$.  My conjecture why $\Omega$ is chosen has to do with $\Omega$ looking like $C$ rotated (in serif fonts) and it also is a corruption of $\Lambda$.